# Possible to access nested table attributes in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

My database schema includes a model(Tasks) that has_one of 14 different types of hazards. For example here is a pseudo relational structure.

```
Task -> has_one Biohazard
     -> has_one Fallhazard
```

In the Task model I currently am trying to implement validation to determine when the forms for each of the hazards has been completed. The condition for this I want to use in my tasks model is as follows.

```
    if self.Biohazard.total < 1000
       self.date_completed = Date.today
    end
```

I am currently getting the error "Undefined method" for this Biohazard.total. Is there a way to make that attribute accessible inside of the Task model?

Comment: `attr_accessible :biohazard`. It's `if self.biohazard.count < 1000`...

Comment: I tried adding that to the model. It did not seem to work. Still giving me an undefined method error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as in the **Biohazard** model you have:

```
attr_accessible :total
```

All you should need in the Task model is:

```
self.biohazard.total
```

to get the total.

Comment: I figured out the issue. It was a simple oversight. The error was because the line in the table had not been "created" yet so it was a nil value. Thanks for the help!.